# How to display long numbers without scientific notation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, formatting, scientific-notation

How to display long numbers without scientific notation in Matlab?

`format long g` doesn't help

```
>> A=single([1456267123000 16.5])
A =
  1×2 single row vector
    1.456267e+12            16.5
>> format long g
>> A
A =
  1×2 single row vector
    1.456267e+12            16.5
```

---

I would expect the output like this

```
    1456267123000           16.5
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what output you're trying to get? Would you like it to be displayed like that for all outputs or just in tables (or custom classes)? If it's a custom class, you should be able to override its `disp` (or `display`, I can't remember) function to use `sprintf` with the desired format...

Comment: Table is 1x2 row vector, not a custom class. It contains numbers. I wan't all numbers displayed without exponential (scientific) notation.

Answer (score 4):

- If you can do with displaying just two decimals, you can use `format bank`:

  ```
  >> format long
  >> pi*1e6
  ans =
       3.141592653589793e+06
  >> pi*1e25
  ans =
       3.141592653589793e+25

  >> format bank
  >> pi*1e6
  ans =
      3141592.65
  >> pi*1e25
  ans =
   31415926535897934939029504.00
  ```
- Or use the more explicit and flexible [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) approach:

  ```
  >> sprintf('%.7f', pi*1e6) % fixed-point, 7 decimals
  >> disp(sprintf('%.7f', pi*1e6))
  3141592.6535898
  ```

  If you just want to display the result you can also use, as noted by [@Dev-iL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3372061/dev-il),

  ```
  >> fprintf(1, '%.7f\n', pi*1e6) % fixed-point, 7 decimals
  3141592.6535898
  ```

  or even

  ```
  >> fprintf('%.7f\n', pi*1e6) % fixed-point, 7 decimals
  3141592.6535898
  ```

Comment: Can `sprintf` print a matrix?

Comment: @Dims It can print a row vector: `sprintf('%.7f ', [pi*1e6 1e9])`. For a matrix you would need to do some manual formatting

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [`mat2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html) which allows you to specify the desired number of digits of precision, and also works for matrices. For example:

```
>> mat2str(pi, 30)
ans =
    '3.14159265358979311599796346854'

>> mat2str([1456267123000 16.5], 20)
ans =
    '[1456267123000 16.5]'
```